# Search for rows containing regex with my matchstring

Tags: mysql, regex

My users enter a regular expression of URLs in the app. I have to return the rows with regular expressions that matched given url.

I have a table like this:

```
+----+-----------------------+--------------------------+
| id | Survey                | URL Regexp               |
+----+-----------------------+--------------------------+
|  1 | User Age survey       | http://*.google.com/*    |
|  2 | Payment intent survey | http://mail.google.com/* |
|  3 | User Country info     | *reader.google.com*      |
|  4 | Company information   | http://facebook.com/*    |
|  5 | Satisfaction survey   | http://*twitter.com/*    |
+----+-----------------------+--------------------------+
```

I want to run a query against a url, `http://mail.google.com/index.html` and see `(1, 2)` as a result (i.e. `User Age Survey` and `Payment intent survey` records).

I want a run a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM surveys where MATCH_REGEXP('http://mail.google.com/index.html')
```

I wasn't able to find any documentation for such expression. What would be the best way to solve this?

Comment: So, what was the question again?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, added more details for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [working](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6fea/1/0) sqlfiddle example.

Given you have this data:

```
CREATE TABLE surveys (
  id int auto_increment primary key, 
  survey varchar(30), 
  url_regex varchar(30)
);

INSERT INTO surveys (survey, url_regex) VALUES
('User Age survey',       'http://.*.google.com/*'),
('Payment intent survey', 'http://mail.google.com/*'),
('User Country info',     '*reader.google.com*'),
('Company information',   'http://facebook.com/*'),
('Satisfaction survey',   'http://*twitter.com/*');
```

You can do this query to achieve what you want:

```
SELECT id FROM surveys
WHERE 'http://mail.google.com/index.html' REGEXP url_regex;
```

The result will be:

```
1
2
```

Please, note that in order to achieve desired result, i.e. `(1, 2)`, "User Age survey" regular expression had to be fixed by prepending a dot before the first asterisk.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Also, never knew about sqlfiddle. Thanks for that.